Can a sentence with a relative that-clause be interrupted with a new independent clause and a comma?
I was very interested in the following sentence from the compilation The Colored Lands by a youthful G.K. Chesterton, in, more specifically, "The Taming of the Nightmare." For context, a boy Jack has tamed a black steed named The Nightmare and is riding her (she IS a "mare" haha) into town in a very funny scene.

Leading her with all speed to the nearest town he interviewed a blacksmith, who agreed to shoe her for the usual consideration.

Now I'm interested in this sentence:

But the curious, not to say discommoding, part of the proceeding was that the Nightmare  who walked mildly as a lamb while Jack himself was holding her, no sooner did the latter let go and the blacksmith approached her with a shoe than she gave a demoniac roar and kicked him through the roof.

I find this to be wonderful, hilarious narration, but I was curious if it is actually a complete sentence.  I expect a verbal phrase to follow after "that the Nightmare..." The curious ... part of the proceeding was that the Nightmare [DID SOMETHING].
No sooner did ... than is an independent clause; it interrupts my verbal phrase expectation with an independent clause stating that she performed an action.
The sentence as it currently stands reads to me like this:  The curious part was that the Nightmare, she kicked him through the roof.
The only way I could think to make it grammatically correct was to use a — instead of a comma (before the "no sooner") to indicate a break in the sentence. Or reword it into two sentences.
Is my thinking on the right track here?

It's technically a content clause (traditionally called a "noun clause") not a relative clause. But I'm not sure either. There seems to be one other mistake here, namely the use of "approached" instead of "approach."

The sentence is missing something. She is calm with the owner and she kicked the blacksmith. But something does not hold together. I'd like to see "that while the Nightmare..."

It's deliberately convoluted for humorous effect and certainty shouldn't be viewed as a model. There's probably more than one way to parse it but the bit starting "the nightmare" seems to be somewhat analogous to topic-fronting as in "The girl you met last night, did you kiss her?"

The way I understand it is that the main clause is everything starting with "no sooner di the latter". The previous clause sets the context and establishes the reference for "the latter".

"the latter let go" means "Jack let go of her".
